# Turning off the blinking cursor in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, ide, qt-creator, usability

I was wondering how the blinking cursor in Qt Creator could be turned off?

As a matter of personal preference, I keep cursor blinking off at the OS level since it can get quite annoying after a while. Unfortunately, Qt Creator does not seem to respect that. I tried looking for an option to turn it off in the IDE but couldn't find any.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: A blinking cursor drives me nuts. (And no, I don't suffer from any condition.) I would think that this was a personal quirk, but then it was a bit of a relief to know that there are many like me. In fact, there is whole page devoted to that: how to stop the cursor from blinking in various IDEs (http://www.jurta.org/en/prog/noblink). Also try googling a bit for "how to turn off blinking cursor" and you will find many who have the same problem as mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the blinking coursor is VERY annoying! It hardly makes it possible to me to work with QtCreator at all... Unfortunately there is probably no way to turn it off or to change the blinking frequency. So what i suggest is:

1) change the color of the cursor to be less harming... for example to grey instead of black. You can do it in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor . Remember that you are not allowed by QtCreator to make any changes to the Default Color Scheme, so you need to click "Copy.." first and than you can make changes to colors. Change the "Text" color - it will change the color of the cursor (but the color of text too... :( ) - but that's the only way to do it I think

2) Alternatevly you can change the version of QtCreator you're using to some older ones. As I remeber older versions of QtCreator did resect Opereting System setting related to cursor blinking rate (for now I'm using QtCreator v.5.2.1 so you need to search for some older version).

Good luck! :)

Comment: There is no QtCreator v5.2.1! Also, the question was how to turn it off. You have not really answered that other than a "probably". The corresponding bugreport was already showed in here. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 4):

> I tried looking for an option to turn it off in the IDE but couldn't find any. Nothing yet? :(

Unfortunately, there is no such an option. It is somewhat rarity what you are asking for, so that may well explain why there is none implemented yet.

Here you can find the corresponding bugreport on their issue tracker:

[Cursor blink rate does not respect system settings](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37200)

Comment: @Najeeb: I am not sure why you withdrew the selection. The other answer is guessing that it might not be possible, and my solution proves that for sure with the corresponding bug report. I also gave it much earlier than the other. The rest in the other answer seems to be off-topic to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As QtCreator simply follows your operating system settings try to disable it there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in QT Creator (Comunity Edition) Qt Creator 3.5.1 (opensource).

In the Editor, I found the "Use Vim-Style Editing" was on.

In Edit -> Advance -> and bottom of the drop down menu the "Use Vim-Style Editing" option has the check mark. I unchecked it and it now works as I want it to.

Comment: Ah! Thank-you!  I was here to find out about turning the blinking cursor **on**.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late to the party... but I've always been annoyed by this as well.

OP didn't specify any OS, this probably applies to Linux only.

Realized that actually all Qt5 applications disregard the DE settings. How rude!

A kind soul has implemented a very slight override that fixes this problem:

https://github.com/igogo/qt5noblink

It's a bit of a hassle to use as `LD_PRELOAD` must be used, but it's always possible to edit the `.desktop` file to do this globally, or make a small script to start it.

Someone with some Windows-fu might be able to achieve something equivalent for that platform.

But seriously, the code for this is *tiny*! How difficult would it be to implement this officially?  :(